# Storing a string in a MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am using PHP to handle my html forms and a MySQL database to store the data. Users can upload posts on my web app with only one problem. If they use "returns" in the textarea it doesn't come back from the database that way. What can I do so that I store the "returns"?

Example

User Input:

```
This is a 
string.
```

Output from the database:

```
This is a string.
```

I want the output to match the input.

Comment: sigh, asked so many times

Comment: What field type are you storing it as?

Comment: You might want to check the source code of the page; you _are_ storing the returns.

Comment: @Dagon: That question concerned a string in which the newlines were already escaped - not a duplicate of this question.

Comment: @eggyal well just to lazy to find a real duplicate there are so many.

Comment: Step 1: Get an HTML book.

Answer (score 4):

A textarea uses newlines instead of BR's

If you are using PHP, try using [**'nl2br()'**](http://php.net/nl2br), this converts all the newlines in a textarea to BR's which should fix your content.

**EDIT**

Use this on your Database output.